# ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from partially initialized module ' ' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I create a Pentest tool for educational purposes, so the old version was written using python 2, then I convert it to python 3 and when I try to run the main file `pxxtf.py` I got multiple errors, I correct most of them but for this one about Circular Import, I try multiple fixes from forums and StackOverFlow and nothing work with me.

When I try to run the main script :

```sh
sudo python3 pxxtf.py
```

I got these errors :

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pxxtf.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core.excute import main
  File "/home/yezz123/Documents/PXXTF/core/excute.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pxxtf import *
  File "/home/yezz123/Documents/PXXTF/pxxtf.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core.excute import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from partially initialized module 'core.excute' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/yezz123/Documents/PXXTF/core/excute.py)
```

- For the code, this is the main `pxxtf.py`

```py
from core.excute import main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
import sys
from core.excute import main
if __name__ == 'main':
    sys.exit(main._main())
```

and this is the `excute.py`

```py
import os
import sys
import core
from time import sleep, time
from pxxtf import *
from core.exploit import clean
from core.banner import banner, PXXTF
# Set color
R = '\033[31m'  # Red
N = '\033[1;37m'  # White
G = '\033[32m'  # Green
O = '\033[0;33m'  # Orange
B = '\033[1;34m'  #Blue
E = '\033[0m'  # End
if not os.geteuid() == 0:  #Detected user root
    sys.exit(
        """\033[1;91m\n[!] Pentest Tools Framework run as root!!. \n\033[1;m"""
    )
if __name__ == "__main__" or clean() or banner() or PXXTF():
    main()


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            PXXTF = eval(input("Pentest>> "))
            if PXXTF == 'use modules/exploits':
                core.menu.exploits()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'use modules/scanners':
                core.menu.scan()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'use modules/password':
                core.menu.pas1()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'use modules/post':
                core.menu.post()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'use modules/listener':
                core.menu.listener()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'use modules/exploitdb':
                core.menu.exploit_db()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'use modules/tools':
                core.menu.tools()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'shell':
                core.exploit.commands()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'show modules':
                core.help.modules()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'ipconfig':
                core.exploit.ip1()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'show options':
                core.help.help()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'update':
                core.exploit.update()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'about':
                core.banner.info()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'credits':
                core.banner.credits()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'banner':
                clean(), banner(), PXXTF(), main()
            elif PXXTF == 'clear':
                core.menu.exploit.clean()
                main()
            elif PXXTF == 'exit':
                core.banner.exits()
                exit()
            else:
                print(("Wrong Command => ", PXXTF))
                print(("" + N + "" + B + "[" + R + "!" + B + "] " + N +
                    "Please enter 'show options'"))
                main()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt):
            print(
                ("\n" + R + "[*] (Ctrl + C ) Detected, Trying To Exit ...\n"))
            time.sleep(2)
            print(("" + G + "[*] Thank You For Using Pentest Framework =)\n"))
            time.sleep(3)
            exit()
```

- To Test the full code you can found it here :
  https://github.com/gdgsnf/PXXTF

Comment: lah m3ak asi yezz123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying it all: "most likely due to a circular import".

*pxxtf.py*

```
from core.excute import main
```

*excute.py*

```
from pxxtf import *
```

Remove one of the imports listed above and it should work. Either way, in Python you cannot have scripts mutually importing each other.